# Change or remove default web3 wallet on Android

Tags: web3-providers

I accidentally chose Ledger as the default wallet for DApps in the Android pop-up when I use Metamask also. How do I remove the default so that I can choose which wallet I want to use?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Settings.
2. Select Apps.
3. Select Default Apps.
4. Select Opening Links.
5. Under Installed Apps, click on the default App that you want to reset.
6. Under Open by default, click the clear button.